# Is it possible to permanently change Bool Value with Async Task?

Tags: c#, boolean, discord, discord.net

I'm working on a Discord Bot that will allow moderators to revoke usability of a function (dice roll). My goal was to have it where if `bool a = true; roll the dice`. `bool a = false; deny`. The moderators would change the bool with a separate function where they could change the boolean value of a and have it stay that way.

I've tried assigning the boolean to a separate class and using get and set, but the value is either not changing or changing back immediately.

```
[Command("diceRoll")]
[Summary("Turns on/off the ability to use the Dice Roll function")]
public async Task DiceRoll(string toggle)
{
    switch (toggle)
    {
        case "on":
        case "On":
        case "ON":
            diceToggle.DiceBool = true;
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Dice Roll Function: ON");
            break;

        case "off":
        case "Off":
        case "OFF":
            diceToggle.DiceBool = false;
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Dice Roll Function: OFF");
            break;

        default:
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Dice Roll Function: ERROR");
            break;
    }
}

[Command("roll")]
[Summary("Dice Roll")]
public async Task Dice(int number)
{
    if (diceToggle.DiceBool == true)
    {
        int randNumber = rand.Next(1, number);
        if (randNumber == 8 || randNumber == 11 || randNumber == 18)
        { await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You rolled an " + randNumber + "."); }
        else 
        { await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You rolled a " + randNumber + "."); }
    }
    else if (diceToggle.DiceBool == false)
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("This feature has been disabled.");
    }
    else
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Something broke, please fix.");
        }
    }
}

public class Game
{
    private bool diceBool;
    public bool DiceBool
    {
        get { return diceBool; }
        set
        {
            if (diceBool != value)
            {
                diceBool = value;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I'm expecting that when the "diceRoll on/off" command is called, the "roll" command will stop working or work again. Currently, the command is called, but the boolean value isn't changing or not staying changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not able to "save" the value is because of how modules work in Discord.Net. Similar to ASP.NET, the modules are transient, meaning they are destroyed from the memory after execution. Please check out the full detail [here](https://docs.stillu.cc/faq/commands/dependency-injection.html#what-is-a-service-why-does-my-module-not-hold-any-data-after-execution)

Comment: This actually explains a lot, thank you! I'll look into this more.